# Share functions across colaboratory files

Tags: python-3.x, google-colaboratory

I'm sharing a colaboratory file with my colleagues and we are having fun with it. But it's getting bigger and bigger, so we want to offload some of the functions to another colaboratory file. How can we load one colaboratory file into another?

Answer (score 3):

There's no way to do this right now, unfortunately: you'll need to move the code into a .py file that you load (say by cloning from github).

Comment: thanks, what a pity. this would be a great add on on functionality.